# RavenDB Multiple databases are not supported in the embedded API currently

Tags: unit-testing, ravendb

I'm using a `EmbdeddedDocumentStore`, running in-memory, when unit testing my application.

My account sign-up controller needs to create a new database for the tenant. It's calling `EnsureDatabaseExists(newTenantId)`.

This results in the following exception:

```
Multiple databases are not supported in the embedded API currently
```

How can I work-around this? Do I have to spin up a non-embedded RavenDB server?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to actually run against an embedded RavenDB in-memory instance during testing, and you are using a full RavenDB server in production, then you can just add some code to check which flavor you are using:

```
if (!(documentStore is EmbeddableDocumentStore))
  documentStore.DatabaseCommands.EnsureDatabaseExists(newTenantId);
```

You'll also want to make sure you are not trying to switch to the `newTenantId` database when opening your session.  You may need some conditional logic there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well the error message seems pretty clear... either change your code to not require multiple databases OR use the non-embedded store OR nag the RavenDB guys to add support for this scenario.

Comment: Or mock the IDocumentStore in the unit test for the sign-up controller.